# Select random string from array in the Notification's description, Flutter Notifications

Tags: flutter

I want to build an app which send daily a notification with fixed title but with random description
so i tried to make an array and select random string but it doesn't work, it selects same string every time, actually it selects only once and repeat it. in my test i used every minute but i think whatever works for it will work for daily, also I tried to but a background image but i think it's impossible.

repeated every minute code:
I made a lot of different codes but this is the most one that make sense.

```
Future<void> repeatNotification() async {
    // define the specifications

    var androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'CHANNEL_ID 3',
      'CHANNEL_NAME 3',
      "CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION 3",
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High,
      styleInformation: DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
      playSound: true,
      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
    );
    var iosChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(androidChannelSpecifics, iosChannelSpecifics);

    //variables we need in periodical method
    print('hi');
    int x = 0;
    List<String> verses = [
      'a',
      'b',
      'c',
      'd',
      'e',
      'f',
      'g',
      'h',
      'i',
      'j',
      'k',
      'l',
      'm',
      'n',
      '0',
      'p',
      'q'
    ];
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      ++x,
      'Some title',
      '${verses[new Random().nextInt(verses.length - 1)]}',
      RepeatInterval.EveryMinute,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'I hate myself',
    );
  }
```

to run this code when app is opened, I placed it in async method and placed the method in the initState() of the home class

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notificationPlugin
        .setListenerForLowerVersions(onNotificationInLowerVersions);
    notificationPlugin.setOnNotificationClick(onNotificationClick);
    waitingDestiny();
    }

  void waitingDestiny()async{
      await notificationPlugin.repeatNotification();
    // await notificationPlugin.showDailyAtTime();
  }
```

complete code [here](https://github.com/2Math0/flutter-Local-notification-guide)

I really will be so thankful if you helped me to solve this out i was stuck in this for 48 hours with no rest, I only want to achieve a daily notification with random description in it, I tried Local Notification but any method will be amazing.